# Is it possible to content projection in angular material table version 11?

Tags: angular, datatable, angular-material, projection

Got a question regarding angular material v11. I want to make a content projection to display cells which I need for business purposes. All I did right now is something like that:

[Here you can find a sample from stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-itg3nh?file=src/main.ts)

Unfortunately, I got an error which means: `Cannot read property 'template' of undefined`. As I'm looking to object `matColumnDef` there are some fields which missing like `MatHeaderRowDef` and `MatFooterRowDef`.

To do that I used this sample which works fine:

[working sample](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3dlbca?file=src/app/components/dyn-table/dyn-column.component.ts)

Do you know how could I potentially solve this issue? Nice to see all tips!

Comment: The working sample doesn't seem to be working anymore. I'm getting "can't find package: core-js".

Looks like you attempted to update [this example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wm1psg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcomponents%2Fdyn-table%2Fdyn-table.component.ts)? I haven't been able to find a newer example of this working than Angular 6.